# should we consider \$R_{out}\$ for \$\omega_{out}\$ in transfer function?

Tags: transfer-function

The following is from the book [Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), Page 180, *Example 6.5*

compute the transfer function of the common-gate stage.
[image]

$$\omega_{in} = \left[(C_{GS} + C_{SB}) (R_S \parallel R_{in}) \right]^{-1}$$

$$\Rightarrow \omega_{in} = \left[(C_{GS} + C_{SB}) (R_S \parallel \frac{1} {g_m+g_{mb}}) \right]^{-1}$$

$$\omega_{out} = \left[(C_{DG} + C_{DB}) R_D \right]^{-1}$$

The book consider input resistance for \$\omega_{in}\$.

$$R_{in} = \frac{1} {g_m+g_{mb}}$$

However, I think we should also include \$R_{out}\$ for \$\omega_{out}\$.

The following is the output resistance. Neglecting channel-length modulation, \$r_{out}\$ should be removed from the following hybrid \$\pi\$ model.

[image]

$$R_{out} = \frac{V_X} {I_X} = R_S$$

$$\omega_{out} = \left[(C_{DG} + C_{DB}) (R_D \parallel R_{out})\right]^{-1}$$

$$\Rightarrow \omega_{out} = \left[(C_{DG} + C_{DB}) (R_D \parallel R_{S})\right]^{-1}$$

Comment: Neglecting channel-length modulation, output impedance is RD. Your calculation Vx/Ix is wrong. It should be infinity.

Comment: @internet How do you know \$R_{out}\$ is infinity?

Comment: `Vs = Ix*Rs`  and  `Ix = gm*V1= - gm*Ix*Rs`
or `Ix*(1+ gm*Rs) = 0`
so `Ix  = 0` and `Vx/Ix = ∞` .

Comment: @internet (1+ gm*Rs) could also be 0.

Comment: No, both gm and Rs are positive.